# What is the difference between checking out branches and tags on Production?

Tags: git, deployment, production, git-tag

We deploy `PROD` branch on production.
My team has the policy that the any merge to `PROD` will constitute a new version and a `vX.Y.Z` tag will be added for it.

Currently we've checked out the `PROD` branch on production server.
Someone recently pointed that instead of branch, the tag should be checked out.

Question:
Since the latest tag is at the tip of the branch, what is the difference between checking out the tag and checking out the branch?
What is recommended?
What are advantages/disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 0):

A tag is immutable (it references a fixed commit), so you are *sure* of what you are checking out.
A opposed to a branch, which will checkout the latest commit on it.

If that commit, for any reason, has no tag... it would still be checked out.

So [annotated tags](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) are recommended.